# Slicing multiple values into single column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The dataframe below is populated by pd.read_sql. How do I select the wf value for every unique Group / SubGroup pair where the book_date == start_date and store it in the column "new".

*I have asterisk'd the rows for additional clarity, the asterisk is not in the dataset.

```
|       | Group | SubGroup  | book_date | start_date | wf   | co2      | new |
|-------|-------|-----------|-----------|------------|------|----------|-----|
| 236   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 3/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.04 | NaN      |     |
| 239   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 4/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.05 | NaN      |     |
| 1178  | Virgo*| Milkyway* | 5/1/1985* | 5/1/1985*  | 0.06*| 0.004179*|     |
| 535   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 6/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.07 | 0.008245 |     |
| 1056  | Virgo | Andromeda | 6/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.57 | NaN      |     |
| 1046  | Virgo | Andromeda | 7/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.58 | NaN      |     |
| 956   | Virgo*| Andromeda*| 8/1/1993* | 8/1/1993*  | 1.59*| 0.006688*|     |
| 776   | Virgo | Andromeda | 9/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.60 | 0.012917 |     |
```

This is the expected result.

```
|       | Group | SubGroup  | book_date | start_date | wf   | co2      | new  |
|-------|-------|-----------|-----------|------------|------|----------|------|
| 236   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 3/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.04 | NaN      | 0.06 |
| 239   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 4/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.05 | NaN      | 0.06 |
| 1178  | Virgo*| Milkyway* | 5/1/1985* | 5/1/1985*  | 0.06*| 0.004179*| 0.06 |
| 535   | Virgo | Milkyway  | 6/1/1985  | 5/1/1985   | 0.07 | 0.008245 | 0.06 |
| 1056  | Virgo | Andromeda | 6/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.57 | NaN      | 1.59 |
| 1046  | Virgo | Andromeda | 7/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.58 | NaN      | 1.59 |
| 956   | Virgo*| Andromeda*| 8/1/1993* | 8/1/1993*  | 1.59*| 0.006688*| 1.59 |
| 776   | Virgo | Andromeda | 9/1/1993  | 8/1/1993   | 1.60 | 0.012917 | 1.59 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create the column new based on the condition and then fillna

```
df['new']=np.where(df['book_date'] == df['start_date'], df['wf'],np.nan)

df['new'] = df.groupby(['Group', 'SubGroup']).new.apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())


        Group   SubGroup    book_date   start_date  wf      co2         new
236     Virgo   Milkyway    3/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.04    NaN         0.06
239     Virgo   Milkyway    4/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.05    NaN         0.06
1178    Virgo   Milkyway    5/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.06    0.004179    0.06
535     Virgo   Milkyway    6/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.07    0.008245    0.06
1056    Virgo   Andromeda   6/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.57    NaN         1.59
1046    Virgo   Andromeda   7/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.58    NaN         1.59
956     Virgo   Andromeda   8/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.59    0.006688    1.59
776     Virgo   Andromeda   9/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.60    0.012917    1.59
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I could not find any documentation on .new. Can you give me a brief intuition on what it's doing? Logically it seems like it would overwrite any existing data.

Comment: @Quasar, the idea here is to first check for the condition book_date == start_date and create a column with values of wf where the cond is true and NaN where it is false. Now groupby Group and SubGroup and fill the missing values by using bfill and ffill for the column new. Here new is not a method, its just the name of the column we created in the previous step. Another way of writing df.groupby(['Group', 'SubGroup'])['new'].apply........

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I did not realize that pandas columns could be called without the [''] formatting. Next mission is to learn .apply I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your data

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df.head()
df.replace({'\*': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)

def gen_new_col(frame):
    if frame['book_date'] == frame['start_date']:
        return frame['wf']
    else:
        return 'ignore'

df['new_col'] = df.apply(gen_new_col, axis=1)
df['g_subg'] = df['Group'] + "|" + df['SubGroup']

df

    Group   SubGroup    book_date   start_date  wf  co2 new_col g_subg
0   Virgo   Milkyway    3/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.04    NaN ignore  Virgo|Milkyway
1   Virgo   Milkyway    4/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.05    NaN ignore  Virgo|Milkyway
2   Virgo   Milkyway    5/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.06    0.004179    0.06    Virgo|Milkyway
3   Virgo   Milkyway    6/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.07    0.008245    ignore  Virgo|Milkyway
4   Virgo   Andromeda   6/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.57    NaN ignore  Virgo|Andromeda
5   Virgo   Andromeda   7/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.58    NaN ignore  Virgo|Andromeda
6   Virgo   Andromeda   8/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.59    0.006688    1.59    Virgo|Andromeda
7   Virgo   Andromeda   9/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.6 0.012917    ignore  Virgo|Andromeda

# Get a lookup
valid = df[df['new_col'] != 'ignore']
lookup = dict(zip(valid['g_subg'], valid['new_col']))
lookup
{'Virgo|Andromeda': '1.59', 'Virgo|Milkyway': '0.06'}

# Bring it back in
df['final_value']  = df['g_subg'].map(lambda x: lookup[x])
df

    Group   SubGroup    book_date   start_date  wf  co2 new_col g_subg  final_value
0   Virgo   Milkyway    3/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.04    NaN ignore  Virgo|Milkyway  0.06
1   Virgo   Milkyway    4/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.05    NaN ignore  Virgo|Milkyway  0.06
2   Virgo   Milkyway    5/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.06    0.004179    0.06    Virgo|Milkyway  0.06
3   Virgo   Milkyway    6/1/1985    5/1/1985    0.07    0.008245    ignore  Virgo|Milkyway  0.06
4   Virgo   Andromeda   6/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.57    NaN ignore  Virgo|Andromeda 1.59
5   Virgo   Andromeda   7/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.58    NaN ignore  Virgo|Andromeda 1.59
6   Virgo   Andromeda   8/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.59    0.006688    1.59    Virgo|Andromeda 1.59
7   Virgo   Andromeda   9/1/1993    8/1/1993    1.6 0.012917    ignore  Virgo|Andromeda 1.59
```